# How to kill the main thread, from another thread (in Java) by RESTful web services call?

Tags: java

Say, I have a Java application running, and I have provided RESTful web services call (via Java Jersey). First, am I right that every invocation of a HTTP RESTful request (or servlet request) runs on a different thread from the main thread? And if so, if I provide a RESTful call to kill the app, how can it reach the main thread (the one started by the main() method) to kill it and subsequently stop the program?

Note: the reason I'm asking this is I need to do a graceful shutdown of the main thread (and the program).

Comment: What is the main thread doing while the app is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your restful service should treat a shutdown request the same as any other request.

For example, if your app was an online store, you might have calls like `processOrder` or `getInventory`. These calls have access to many things in your app, right? Well, just make a new call called `shutdown`. This call will shut the gates to future calls, wait for existing calls to finish, save in-memory information to the DB, and other safe shutdown procedures.

It's really just another call. I wouldn't worry so much about "stopping the main method" from a call - think in terms of logical behavior, not technical behavior.

It would appear for Jersey, you're looking for `client.destroy();`.

Comment: I don't understand, then how would the running app be stopped?

Comment: Looks like you simply destroy the client... make a reference to it available to your shutdown procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can terminate the Java VM with the following. Since the VM is stopped, all threads should be terminated by it as well...

```
System.exit(0);
```

You can check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) for details about using that.

Comment: This is too abrupt. I forgot to mention that there is graceful shutdown process.

Comment: @ikevinjp You asked how to kill the main thread, and I aswered how to kill the main thread :) A bit harsh to downvote for that.

Comment: @ikevinjp: That is a very significant thing to forget to mention! Can you edit your question to describe the graceful shutdown process? Basically, the kill request will need to trigger that.

Comment: I did not do the downvote - it was someone else. I just gave you an upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Jersey service is an instance of

```
com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`
```

... which you created by calling

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(...)
```

Assuming that you can get hold of the HttpServer instance, you can shutdown the service by calling the `stop(int)` method on it.  There is no reason why you can't do this from one of your request handlers.